# How to determine if a number is odd or even without mod -or- bitwise operations?

Tags: code-challenge

How to determine if a number is odd or even without mod -or- bitwise operations?

This challenge is grossly inefficient, but challenges your ability to think outside the box for a creative solution.

***EDIT***:

Please create a function. Also, while regex is a fun response, the function should accept *any* valid number.

***BACKGROUND***:
This question stems from my earliest programming days.  The homework for our first day of class was to write a simple program that printed 'odd' or 'even'.  Being the brat I was, I didn't read the book we had for the class where it simply showed us how to use `%` to determine that.  I spent about a half hour pacing back in forth in my room trying to think of a way to do this and had remembered from the lecture that numbers can lose and gain precision as they are cast from one primitive type to another.  Therefore, if you took the number, divided it by two and then multiplied it back didn't equal the original number, then you would know that the number was odd.

I was stunned the next day, while our instructor was evaluating our programs, that he thought that it was the most original, if inefficient, way of solving the problem.

Comment: Should we create a function or a program? How should IO happen if we have to do a program? Please, elaborate further.

Comment: What objective criterion will determine the accepted answer? Code size? Something else?

Comment: Is it definitely a number?  Should it give false positives for a string?

Comment: This has been around for quite a long time, but there doesn't seem to be a winning condition of any kind, which to my mind means there is no game here.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In most programming languages division returns quotient for integers. So you can simply check this

```
(i/2)*2==i
```

Comment: Not necessarily most, I'd say. Many, maybe.

Comment: to ensure it runs properly, you need to make sure you cast everything into an `int`/`long` type

Comment: @warren Depends on the programming language/compiler optimizations/etc. Additionally, you can use `floor()`. That works perfectly in C and C++.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer because it had the widest usability in different languages.  It also happened to be the solution I came up with eons ago to solve the same problem. :)

Comment: Is 0 a even number?

Comment: @userunknown: Yes, zero is even.

Answer (score 72):

### Python

```
print('even' if (-1)**n==1 else 'odd')
```

Comment: The simple beauty / beautiful simplicity of mathematics...very nice!

Comment: I like this one a lot.

Comment: Slow but creative.

Answer (score 21):

### Mathematica

```
SawtoothWave[x / 2] == 0
Exp[I Pi x] - 1 == 0
Sin[5 x / Pi] == 0
```

Comment: Can you split these two solutions into different answers?

Comment: Aren't those four solutions?

Comment: Actually, all built-in names in *Mathematica* are capitalized, so as funny as it looks, you should use `I` and `Pi` instead of `i` and `pi`.

Answer (score 21):

### Brainf*** (179)

This is one of the more interesting problems involving conditional logic that I have done in BF.

```
+[>,]<--------------------------------------->>+++++[>+++++++
++++++>+++++++++++++++<<-]>++++>++++<<+<+<-[>-<-[>+<-[>-<-[>+<-[>-<-[>
+<-[>-<-[>+<-[>-<[-]]]]]]]]]]>[>>>.<<-<-]>[>.<-]
```

It takes a text input with a number. If the number is even, it outputs `E`, and if it is odd, it outputs `O`.

I'm proud enough of it that I'll show off a more human readable form:

```
+[>,]                                                   steps through input until it reaches eof.
<---------------------------------------                gets the numerical value of the last digit
>>+++++[>+++++++++++++>+++++++++++++++<<-]>++++>++++    store E and O
<<+<+<                                                  store a bit indicating parity, and a temporary bit
-[>-<                                                   !1
  -[>+<                                                 && !2
    -[>-<                                               && !3
      -[>+<                                             && !4
        -[>-<                                           && !5
          -[>+<                                         && !6
            -[>-<                                       && !7
              -[>+<                                     && !8
                -[>-<[-]]                               && !9
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
>[>>>.<<-<-]>[>.<-]                                     Display E or O based on the value of the parity bit.
```

Answer (score 16):

### C

Multiplied by itself a few times any even number will overflow to 0 given a finite size integer, and any odd number will continue to have at least the least significant bit set.

```
#include "stdio.h"
long long input=123;
int main(){
    int a;
    for(a=6;a;a--){
        input*=input;
    }
    if(input){
        printf("Odd");
    }
    else{
        printf("Even");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: As a simple function:

```
int isOdd(long long input){
    int a;
    for(a=6;a;a--){
        input*=input;
    }
    return !!input;
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use unsigned integers.  Overflow of signed integers is undefined behavior in C, so optimization could do something weird if it wanted.

Answer (score 13):

### JavaScript

```
/[02468]$/.test(i)
```

yields `true` for an even number. This only works with reasonably sized integers (e.g. not scientific notation when converted to a string and not having a fractional part.)

Comment: To meet the "function" requirement you could change it to simply `/[02468]$/.test`.

Comment: It wasn't exactly clear in the question but it could be possible that the input isn't a number at all, `/[02468]$/.test('I am a fake even number 0')`.  In that case you could do `/^[0-9].[02468]$/.test(i)`

Comment: `/-?^\d*[02468]$/` would be a little stricter than your regex. You would need more work for this to work properly for numbers that are toString'ed using scientific notation.

Answer (score 13):

**Python** (Slow)

```
n=1234
while n > 1: n -= 2 #slow way of modulus.
print "eovdedn"[n::2]
```

Comment: Works for positive...i suppose i could add a `abs()` call in the beginning.

Comment: @Josh: That trick appeared here a few times already by now :)

Comment: Credits to gnibblr :)

Comment: @Joey: I didn't figure it was new, but style doesn't have to be original. :)

Answer (score 12):

### Python

Since I'm not really sure what the scoring criteria are, here's a bunch of solutions I've come up with for amusement's sake. Most of them use `abs(n)` to support negative numbers. Most, if not all, of them should never be used for real calculation.

This one is kind of boring:

```
from __future__ import division
def parity(n):
    """An even number is divisible by 2 without remainder."""
    return "Even" if n/2 == int(n/2) else "Odd"
```

---

```
def parity(n):
    """In base-10, an odd number's last digit is one of 1, 3, 5, 7, 9."""
    return "Odd" if str(n)[-1] in ('1', '3', '5', '7', '9') else "Even"
```

---

```
def parity(n):
    """An even number can be expressed as the sum of an integer with itself.
      
    Grossly, even absurdly inefficient.
    
    """
    n = abs(n)
    for i in range(n):
        if i + i == n:
            return "Even"
    return "Odd"
```

---

```
def parity(n):
    """An even number can be split into two equal groups."
    g1 = []
    g2 = []
    for i in range(abs(n)):
        g1.append(None) if len(g1) == len(g2) else g2.append(None)
    return "Even" if len(g1) == len(g2) else "Odd"
```

---

```
import ent # Download from: http://wstein.org/ent/ent_py
def parity(n):
    """An even number has 2 as a factor."""
    # This also uses modulo indirectly
    return "Even" if ent.factor(n)[0][0] == 2 else "Odd"
```

---

And this is my favorite although it unfortunately doesn't work (as pointed out by March Ho below: just because all even numbers are the sum of two primes, doesn't mean that all odd numbers aren't).

```
import itertools
import ent    # Download from: http://wstein.org/ent/ent_py
def parity(n)
    """Assume Goldbach's Conjecture: all even numbers greater than 2 can
    be expressed as the sum of two primes.
        
    Not guaranteed to be efficient, or even succeed, for large n.
    
    """
    # A few quick checks
    if n in (-2, 0, 2): return "Even"
    elif n in (-1, 1): return "Odd"
    if n < 0: n = -n    # a bit faster than abs(n)
    # The primes generator uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes
    # and thus modulo, so this is a little bit cheating
    primes_to_n = ent.primes(n)
    # Still one more easy way out
    if primes_to_n[-1] == n: return "Odd"
    # Brutish!
    elif n in (p1+p2 for (p1, p2) in itertools.product(primes_to_n, primes_to_n)):
        return "Even"
    else:
        return "Odd"
```

Comment: Cute solutions :-)

Comment: Really an old necro, but doesn't your Goldbach's conjecture answer print Even for 9? Seems like a case of [affirming the consequent fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent)

Comment: Yup, you're absolutely, one hundred percent right, @MarchHo. Egg on my face.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell

This is, of course, in no way the creative, thinking-outside-the-box solution you're looking for, but how many times am I going to get to post a Haskell answer shorter than GolfScript, really?  It's really a shame this isn't a code golf.

```
odd
```

But more seriously:

```
data Parity = Even | Odd
            deriving (Show)

parity = p evens odds
  where p (x:xs) (y:ys) i | i == x = Even
                          | i == y = Odd
                          | otherwise = p xs ys i
        evens = interleave [0,2..] [-2,-4..]
        odds = interleave [1,3..] [-1,-3..]
        interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
```

Comment: looks longer than the [GolfScript](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-odd-or-even-without-mod-or-bitwise-operations/2306#2306) answer to me

Comment: I was referring to the first block (`odd`) which is a builtin function that returns True if the number is odd.  That's a complete answer on its own and shorter than the current GolfScript answer (which at the time of writing this is 10 chars, but I expect that to go down).  The question is also a bit underspecified, which is why I assert that `odd` is sufficient.  That may change as well.

Comment: missed the first reply in your answer :)

Comment: At the very least the `parity` algorithm works on all `Num` instances that are integers. That's hot! Though I probably would have done `evens = [0,2..] >>= \n -> [-n, n]`. Similar for odds.

Answer (score 7):

Using a deliberately perverse reading of the question, "How to determine if a number is odd or even", here's a C implementation (assume `bool` and `true` are defined appropriately):

```
bool is_odd_or_even(int n)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The question mentions number, not integer. Number like `0.5` returns `true` when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 7):

What, no randomized algorithms yet??

### C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void prt_parity_of(int n){
  int i,j=2;
  char o[]="eovdedn"
     , f[n=abs(n)]; for(i=n;i-->0;f[i]=1);

  while(j>1){
    while((i=rand()%n)
       == (j=rand()%n)
       || (f[i]&f[j]>0)
       && (f[i]=f[j]=0)
    );for(i=j=0; ++i<n; j+=f[i])
  ;}for(;j<7;j+=2)putchar(o[j]);
}
```

Randomly pairs numbers in the range 0..*n*-1 until less than 2 are left. It's quite amazingly inefficient: *O*(‌*n*<sup>3</sup>).

---

Completely different:

### Haskell

```
import Data.Complex

ft f = (\ω -> sum[ f(t) * exp(0:+2*pi*ω*t) | t<-[-1,-0.9..1] ] )

data Parity = Even | Odd deriving (Show)

parity n
  | all (\(re:+im) -> abs re > abs im) [ft ((:+0).(^^n)) ω | ω<-[0..20]]  = Even
  | otherwise                                                             = Odd
```

Uses the fact that the Fourier transform of an even function (e.g. `\x->x^^4`) is real, while the Fourier transform of an odd function is imaginary.

Answer (score 6):

### Coq, 103

```
Fixpoint even n:=match n with O=>true|S n=>odd n end with odd n:=match n with O=>false|S n=>even n end.
```

As far as I can tell this is the first coq entry on codegolf.

Even shorter (59):

```
Fixpoint even n:=match n with O=>true|S n=>negb(even n)end.
```

Answer (score 5):

### Windows PowerShell

```
function OddOrEven([long]$n) {
  if (0,2,4,6,8 -contains "$n"[-1]-48) {
    "Even"
  } else {
    "Odd"
  }
}
```

1. Convert to string
2. Pick last letter (digit) (essentially a mod 10).
3. Check if it is 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8.

No bitwise operators, no modulus, as requested.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby

```
n.odd?
```

If you want to print out the result:

```
f[n] = ->(n){puts n.odd?? 'odd' : 'even'}
```

Comment: I'm fairly use ruby uses mod in the `.odd?` definition.

Answer (score 4):

### Unlambda

The world needs more Unlambda.

Unlambda has a killer advantage here: its default (*ahem*) representation for numbers are Church numerals, so all that's needed is to apply them to function binary-not to function true.  Easy!

PS: Markdown and Unlambda are definitely not made for one another.

```
true  = i
false = `ki
not   = ``s``s``s`k``s``si`k`kk`k`kii`k`ki`ki
even? = ``s``si`k``s``s``s`k``s``si`k`kk`k`kii`k`ki`ki`ki
```

Verification for the first few integers:

````
```s``si`k``s``s``s`k``s``si`k`kk`k`kii`k`ki`ki`ki`ki                   => i
```s``si`k``s``s``s`k``s``si`k`kk`k`kii`k`ki`ki`kii                     => `ki
```s``si`k``s``s``s`k``s``si`k`kk`k`kii`k`ki`ki`ki``s``s`kski           => i
```s``si`k``s``s``s`k``s``si`k`kk`k`kii`k`ki`ki`ki``s``s`ksk``s``s`kski =>`ki
````

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript

```
~,2/),1=\;
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python

```
print (["even"] + (["odd", "even"] * abs(n)))[abs(n)]
```

Similar performance to the earlier version. Works for 0 now.

**Incorrect Earlier version:**

```
print ((["odd", "even"] * abs(n))[:abs(n)])[-1]
```

Not particularly efficient; time and memory both obviously O(n): 32 msec for 1,000,000; 2.3 msec for 100000; 3.2 usec for 100. Works with negative numbers. Throws an error for 0, because 0 is neither even nor odd.

Comment: Zero is definitely even.  See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Comment: @jloy: Aw, crap. I thought that was "a feature, not a bug". More revisions...

Answer (score 3):

#### Fractran

```
[65/42,7/13,1/21,17/7,57/85,17/19,7/17,1/3]
```

applied to

```
63*2^abs(n)
```

yields either `5` if `n` is odd or `1` if `n` is even.

**Update**: Much shorter but not so interesting:

```
[1/4](2^abs(n))
```

is `2` for odd `n` and `1` for even `n`.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl

What about

```
use Math::Trig;
print(cos(pi*@ARGV[0])>0?"even":"odd")
```

Answer (score 3):

### MMIX (4 Bytes)

This is kind of cheating. I use neither mod nor bit fiddling operations. It's rather that testing for odd / even numbers is builtin. Assuming that `$3` contains the number to test and the result goes into `$2`:

```
ZSEV $2,$3,1
```

sets `$2` to `1` if `$3` is even and to `0` if not. The mnemnoric `ZSEV` means *zero-set even* and has the following semantics:

```
ZSEV a,b,c: if (even b) a = c; else a = 0;
```

For the above line, `mmixal` generates these four bytes of assembly:

```
7F 02 03 01
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scheme

This is the most inefficient solution I know of.

```
(letrec ([even? (lambda (n)
                 (if (zero? n) "even"
                     (odd? (- n 2))))]
         [odd? (lambda (n)
                 (if (= n 1) "odd"
                     (even? (- n 2))))])
  (even? (read)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 36

```
function(i){while(i>0)i-=2;return!i}
```

Returns `true` if even, `false` if not.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl

```
$n x '0' =~ /^(00)*$/
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python

```
zip((False, True)*(i*i), range(i*i))[-1][0]
```

testing the square of i, so it works for negative numbers too

Answer (score 2):

## F#

Mutual recursion for the win.

A number n is even if it is zero or (n-1) is odd.

A number n is odd if it is unequal to zero and (n-1) is even.

(abs added in case anyone's interested in the parity of negative numbers)

```
let rec even n = n = 0 || odd (abs n - 1) 
    and odd n = n <> 0 && even (abs n - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure

```
  (defmacro even?[n]
  `(= 1 ~(concat (list *) (repeat n -1))))
```

Answer (score 2):

What qualifies as bitwise operations?  Under the hood, integer division by 2 is likely to be implemented as a bit-shift.

Assuming bitshifts aren't out:

## C/C++

```
(unsigned char)((unsigned char)(n > 0 ? n : -n) << 7) > 0 ? "odd" : "even"
```

*edit*  Missed some parentheses, and ultimately changed to remove a shift to make it do less.  You can test this with the following (in *nix):

```
echo 'main(){ std::cout<< (unsigned char)((unsigned char)(n > 0 ? n : -n) << 7) > 0 \
        ? "odd\n" : "even\n";}' \
  | gcc --include iostream -x c++ -o blah -
./blah
```

... though in Linux/tcsh, I had to escape the backslash on `\n` even though it was in single-quotes.  I tested in little & big-endian, it works correctly in both.  Also, I hand-copied this; the computer I'm posting with doesn't have a compiler, so it may have mistakes.

## x86 asm

```
            mov eax, n          # Get the value
            cmp eax,0           # Is it zero?
            jge pos_label       # If >= 0, skip the next part
            neg eax
pos_label:
```

.

```
            imul al, 128
```

or

```
            shl  al, 7
```

or

```
            lea  eax, [eax*8]    # Multiply by 2^3 (left-shift by 3 bits)
            lea  eax, [eax*8]    # ... now it's n*2^6
            lea  eax, [eax*2]    # ... 2^7, or left-shift by 7 bits
```

... followed by:

```
            cmp al,  0          # Check whether the low byte in the low word is zero or not
            jz  even_label      # If it's zero, then it was an even number
            odd_label           # ... otherwise it wasn't
```

Alternatively, the shift & compare stuff could be done this way as well:

```
            sar al,1            # signed integer division by 2 on least-significant byte
            jc  odd_label       # jump if carry flag is set
```

Comment: BTW, `shl` and friends are disallowed...

Answer (score 2):

On a 68000 processor you could move a word value from the address defined by the value to test:

```
 move.l <number to test>,a0
 move.w (a0),d0
 ; it's even if the next instruction is executed
```

and let the hardware trap for address error determine the odd/even nature of the value - if the exception is raised, the value was odd, if not, the value was even:

```
 <set up address error trap handler>
 move.l <pointer to even string>,d1
 move.l <number to test>,a0
 move.w (a0),d0
 <reset address error trap handler>
 <print string at d1>
 <end>

 address_error_trap_handler:
 move.l <pointer to odd string>,d1
 rte
```

Doesn't work on Intel x86 CPUs as those are more flexible about data access.

Answer (score 2):

## Python

I decided to try for the ugliest, most confusing solution I could think of:

```
n=input();r=range(n+1)
print [j for i in zip(map(lambda x:str(bool(x))[4],[8&7for i in r]),
map(lambda x:str(x)[1],[[].sort()for x in r])) for j in i][n]
```

Prints e if even, o if odd.

Answer (score 2):

## Q

Keep subtracting 2 until x<2 then convert to bool

```
{1b$-[;2]/[2<=;abs x]}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica

**Edit**:
This is the unimaginative check that many folks, including me, use. If an integer ends in 0,2,4, 6,or 8, it is even, otherwise odd.

```
f[n_?IntegerQ] := Print[n, " is ", 
If[MemberQ[{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}, IntegerDigits[n][[-1]]], "even.", "odd."]]
```

**Original solution**:

The following is even more unimaginative and uselessly slow  for "large" integers, but in principle, it works.

If an integer has 2 is its lowest prime factor, it is even.

```
f[n_?IntegerQ]:= Print[n, " is ", If[FactorInteger[n][[1, 1]] == 2, "Even", "Odd"]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### scala:

```
scala> def evenOrOdd (n:Int) : Unit = n match {
     | case 0 => println ("even")              
     | case 1 => println ("odd")               
     | case _ => evenOrOdd (n-2) }             
evenOrOdd: (n: Int)Unit

scala> evenOrOdd (123456789)
odd
```

(less than one second)

Answer (score 1):

Are we allowed to submit utterly terrible ways to do this?  If so...

## C

```
#include <stdio>

void oddOrEven(int number)
{
   char test[128];
   sprintf(test, "%d", number);

   int index = strlen(test) - 1;

   if((test[index]=='0')||(test[index]=='2')||(test[index]=='4')||
        (test[index]=='6')||(test[index]=='8'))
   {
      printf("Even.");
   } else {
      printf("Odd.");
   }
}
```

I apologize for any errors, I don't have a chance to compile or test this.  Fixed one bug, per comment by Joey Adams.

This answer is similar to the one posted by idealmachine

Comment: You'll need `strlen(test) - 1` for this to work.  `test[index]` currently refers to the null terminator of the string.

Comment: @Joey Adams Thanks, I knew there'd be at least one bug.

Comment: Considering efficiency isn't a metric here, this solution is as good as any really.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

`sub is_odd {$#{[split/\./,$_[0]/2]}}`

Comment: What's the $#{} do?

Comment: it dereferences the array references `[]` and returns the last index (i.e. N-1 since Perl indexes start at 0). This is essentially `sub is_odd {$input = shift; $input /= 2; my @parts = split /\./, $input; return ( scalar(@parts) - 1) }`

Comment: Thanks that cleared it up, I got the `$#array` bit but I missed that you were turning the ouput of split into a reference with `[]` then dereferenceing with `${}` and adding the `#` to get the last index, very cool.

Comment: its essentially the babycart "operator" `@{[]}`, but the index of that :) http://www.mail-archive.com/fwp@perl.org/msg03595.html

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

### C++ (63)

Token absurd recursive solution. Even golfed!

```
#include <math.h>
bool o(int v){return v==0?false:!o(abs(v)-1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

For C or C++, easy enough:

```
int Temp = 20
double Temp2 = ((double)Temp/2);
Temp2 = Temp2 - ((int)Temp/2);
if(Temp2 != 0.0)
{
    printf("It's odd!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("It's even!\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#

Sorry for my previous response, I'm totally messed up today.

```
bool Even(int i){return i==0||!Even(i-1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isEven(i) {
    return i == 0 || !isEven(i - (i > 0 ? 1 : -1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

return exp(sqrt(-1)*x*pi)==1?"even":"odd";

Comment: Nice approach, what language is this supposed to be, though? Exact complex arithmetic is quite uncommon outside CASs.

Comment: You got me there. I use Matlab a lot, but this isn't real Matlab code. Anyway, it could also be done with a cosine function and a real argument (x*pi).  And as far as exactness goes, even testing within limits would become a problem for large x. (This is my first code golf. Looks like fun!)

Answer (score 1):

## C++11

(for C++03, replace `long long` with `long` and `-2ull` with `-2ul`)

Yet another solution which takes advantage of the fact that integers have finite size, together with the fact that unsigned arithmetic is defined as modulo arithmetic. It also uses the fact that conversion of integer types to `bool` gives `true` iff the converted number is nonzero.

```
bool odd(unsigned long long n) // note: signed->unsigned conversion preserves oddity
{
  return n * (1 + -2ull / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

```
if ((int(($number/2)) * 2) == $number) { print ("even"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash

This script asks [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) whether a number is even or odd:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -s "http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=even($1)" | grep 'is even' > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo Yes
else
    echo No
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, Recduction from Towers of Hanoi

When moving `n` pegs from `A` to `B`, then for even `n`, the first move is `A->C`.
Doesn't work for n=0.

```
data Peg = A|B|C deriving Eq   
third :: Peg -> Peg -> Peg
third x y
    | x/=A && y/=A = A
    | x/=B && y/=B = B
    | x/=C && y/=C = C

data Move = Move Peg Peg deriving Eq

-- Move n pegs from a to b
hanoi :: Int -> Peg -> Peg -> [ Move ]
hanoi 0 _ _ = []
hanoi n a b = (hanoi (n-1) a c) ++ [Move a b] ++ (hanoi (n-1) c b) where
    c = third a b

-- n is even if the first step in moving n discs from A to B is A->C.
iseven :: Int -> Bool
iseven n = (head $ hanoi n A B) == Move A C
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl

This always returns a `.` when the number is odd, and either an integer or nothing when it is even.

```
chop($_=<>/2);print chop
```

If you want it to actually print the word "odd" or "even" then it needs to be expanded to the following:

```
chop($_=<>/2);if(chop=='.'){print"Odd"}else{print"Even"}
```

OR, if you want the program to exit once it gives a result, this can be written as:

```
chop($_=<>/2);if(chop=='.'){die"Odd"}die"Even"
```

Comment: Only works with numbers greater than 18. However, changing `==` to `eq` might fix it (requires an extra space though).

Answer (score 0):

## VB.Net

```
return (i\2)*2=i
```

Notice the use of the backslash operator `\` that performs a integer division and discards any reminders. The usage of a forvard slash operator `/` would not work for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

### [Haskell](http://haskell.org/)

```
odd = (<)0.(^)(-1)
even = (>)0.(^)(-1)
```

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/)

```
odd =: 0>_1&^
even =: 0<_1&^
```

If (-1)<sup>*n*</sup><0, *n* is odd; if 
(-1)<sup>*n*</sup>>0, *n* is even.

```
odd =: [:|[:{:@+.0j1&^
even =: [:|[:{.@+.0j1&^
```

Taking the imaginary/real part of *i*<sup>*n*</sup> would be a neat way to do it too, but needs better thresholding than this.

Answer (score 0):

use queue and push pop, if element remains at last, it's odd, else is even:

```
var q = new Queue<int>();
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   if (q.Count > 0)
     q.Pop();
   else q.Push(0);
}

if (q.Count != 0)
  return "Odd";
return "Even";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python

Somebody already used this idea, but this implementation is more concise:

```
def even(n):return str(n)[-1]in'02468'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Squeak Smalltalk**

Since printing in base 2 would be too obvious and a big waste of time because only the last digit counts

```
odd
    ^(self printStringBase: 2) last = $1
```

I decided to rather print in base 3 to at least scan all the digits

```
odd
    ^self ~= 0 and: [self = 1 or: [((self printStringBase: 3) occurrencesOf: $1) odd]]
```

Of course, if we have more CPU to waste, we can just enumerate

```
odd
    ^(1 to: self abs) inject: false into: [:odd :int | odd not]
```

Finally, if we are impatient, this might be a bit faster

```
odd
    (0 to: self abs by: 2) size - (1 to: self abs by: 2) size = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### R

```
is.even<-function(n){
    options(warn=-1)
    res<-ifelse(sum(matrix(1:abs(n),nrow=2)==1)!=1, "Odd", "Even")
    options(warn=0)
    res
    }
```

The idea is to build a 2-rows matrix with the sequence 1 to the absolute value of n (to allow negative numbers). If the number is odd, the sequence has to be recycled to fill the 2 rows, so the matrix contains twice the number 1.
Due to the method, it doesn't work with large numbers but it works with zero.

```
> is.even(0)
[1] "Even"
> is.even(467)
[1] "Odd"
> is.even(-46798)
[1] "Even"
> is.even(9999999999)
Error in 1:abs(n) : result would be too long a vector
```